# Not able to create SSIS DB without Azure Subscription in SQL server

Tags: sql, ssis

I am trying to create SSISDB in SQL server for testing purpose for ETL purpose . Since i dont have azure subscription i am not able create.

First of all i want to know why i am getting Azure Data factory option in Create Catalog wizard in my ssms .

I have attached images screenshot of wizard with ADF .

Why i am getting ADF . Because of that i am not able to create SSIS DB since i dont have azure subscription . Please help me .

[CreateWizardwithADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnNsb.png)

Comment: I think your screenshot is cut off.  At the bottom there should be an OK button.  Fill in the options and click OK and that should create the catalog on that SQL server.   The "Create SSIS IR" button is if you want to create the runtime in Azure data factory, doesn't mean you are required to.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server installed locally or on your network? You don't need ADF to use the SSISDB as @TimMylott said. But you do need a compatible (2012 + I believe) version... somewhere.

Comment: @TimMylott I am having the same issue and I do not have a hidden OK button.